# WebSocket with Laravel-echo-server: 502 Bad gateway

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

I can't find a solution for more than a week. Everything works fine on the dev server, but not on production. I have no strength, I appeal to you, colleagues :)

I'm using Laravel-echo-server on Socket.io using CloudFlare. When trying to connect, I get an error:
**WebSocketError: Unexpected status code received (502 Bad Gateway)**

**Ubuntu** 16.04.7 LTS, **Laravel Echo Server**: 1.6.1, **NodeJs**: v12.19.0

laravel-echo-server.json:

```
    {
    "authHost": "http://localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "...",
            "key": "..."
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "password": "...",
            "port": "...",
            "db": 0
        },
        "sqlite": {}
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": "",
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {
        "transports": ["websocket", "polling"]
    },
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "*",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

Nginx host:

```
    server {
        listen 8443 ssl;
        server_name domain.tld;       
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/my.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/my.key;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.tld/ws.log info;

        location /ws {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        }
}
```

After start EchoServer i see:

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.6.1

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!
```

Ok, next:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:6001
> OK
```

Next:

```
websocat wss://domain.tld:8443/ws
```

And I get the error:

```
websocat: WebSocketError: Received unexpected status code (502 Bad Gateway)
```

Laravel echo server is running, I can see its events. Tried changing the host in laravel-echo-server.json (127.0.0.1, localhost, null, 0.0.0.0), in nginx proxy to *localhost, 127.0.0.1* - nothing helps. I tried to add *upstreams* in nginx host, it doesn't help.
This information also did not help: https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/issues/273

Please, help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the problem is, but I found a solution.
I've updated a lot: updated Nginx to 1.19.1, possibly installed some additional modules. Installed npm not globally, but locally.
And it worked ...

Attention: this only works if you write **location /socket.io.**
That was not the point for sure:  *"authHost": "http://localhost"*

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is your issue.

```
{
  "authHost": "http://localhost" // This should be your domain name
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the problem goes deeper. I created another question. I think it is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481559/why-isnt-nginx-changing-the-protocol-to-websocket

Comment: And the error would be in the authorization (401, 403), not 502 :D