# Why isn't Nginx changing the protocol to WebSocket?

Tags: laravel, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, laravel-echo

I am trying to run Laracvel-echo.

Host configuration:

```
location /socket.io {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6002/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

I catch headers with Socat:

```
socat -v TCP-LISTEN:6002,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:6001
```

On my DEV server, I see that everything is ok, the protocol is changing **(HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols)**:

```
2020/10/22 13:51:36.147102  length=175 from=0 to=174
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r
Upgrade: websocket\r
Connection: Upgrade\r
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: yU0AKhFOQaw5j9cQS8oq2bjx1pw=\r
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate\r
```

But in PRODUCTION server i see GET protocol **(GET /socket.io HTTP/1.1)**:

```
 2020/10/22 13:50:34.161919  length=588 from=0 to=587
GET /socket.io HTTP/1.1\r
Upgrade: websocket\r
Connection: Upgrade\r
Host: localhost:6002\r
Pragma: no-cache\r
Cache-Control: no-cache\r
Authorization: Basic YWlkYXI6MTIzMTIz\r
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36\r
Origin: chrome-extension://pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo\r
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7\r
Sec-WebSocket-Key: rq5CaFXEzZ/vWSnOJ5H3PA==\r
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits\r
```

My question is related to this: [WebSocket with Laravel-echo-server: 502 Bad gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428863/websocket-with-laravel-echo-server-502-bad-gateway)
Is the NGINX problem or am I wrong?

Help me please!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem is, but I found a solution.
I've updated a lot: updated Nginx to 1.19.1, possibly installed some additional modules. Installed npm not globally, but locally.
And it worked ...

Attention: this only works if you write **location /socket.io.**